# How do I group data in Application Insights and select latest rows?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have custom metric data in application insights similar to:

| timestamp | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05/05/2023, 15:46:43.000 | test1 | 10 |
| 05/05/2023, 16:43:54.000 | test2 | 54 |
| 05/05/2023, 12:32:56.000 | test3 | 76 |
| 05/05/2023, 04:23:41.000 | test2 | 34 |
| 05/05/2023, 09:41:40.000 | test1 | 23 |
| 05/05/2023, 11:09:03.000 | test1 | 12 |

How can I query the data to group the data by name and then select the latest value so I would return the following data?

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| test1 | 12 |
| test2 | 54 |
| test3 | 76 |

Many thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

I think `arg_max` should do the trick:

```
customMetrics
| summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by name
| order by name
| project name, value
```

`*` - instructs to take the whole row